# Issues in running two jquery slideshow on same page

Tags: jquery

I am PHP programmer and mostly used jquery plugins on my website. The problem annoying me is to place two slide show on single page website. There is only one slideshow is running at a time.

Here is the code i'm using..
links for the first slider...

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>

<script src="js/jquery.smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

links for the second one..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
    </script>
```

Hope i'll get som specific ans.. thanx in advance

Comment: What do the #ca-container HTML elements look like?

Comment: for the first one its..
 <div class="slider-wrapper">
        

            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/slides/slide1.png" width="383" height="198" alt="" />
</div>
</div>

Comment: @JasmeetKaurChauhan update your html in your question itself.

Comment: and the second slider container starts..

<div class="container">
    <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
    <div class="ca-wrapper">
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
//content goes on..

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell : #ca-container is look like 

<div class="container">
    <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
    <div class="ca-wrapper">
     <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
      <div class="ca-item-main">
       <div class="ca-icon"></div>

Comment: Are you getting any error messages that might help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: @redlena : No, its not showing any error message, Its just my slideshow is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but you have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
</script>
```

It should probably be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { $('#ca-container').contentcarousel(); });
</script>
```

So it starts on page load rather than depending on where it's placed in the script. See more here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/